# Aplicar el mismo html a un formulario en django

Tags: css, html5, django, django-forms

Buenas tardes estoy cambiando la parte de un modulo de formularios normales a los form que django proporciona, pero al estar queriendo aprovechar el html que se tenia me surgió una duda.

como puedo darle el mismo html que se tenia antes ya que ahora pinto el formulario a través de un ciclo for.

codigo html anterior.

```
 <div class="mb-2">
      <label class="font-weight-medium">Elige un color del producto para agregar al carrito</label>
    </div>
    <div class="card my-2">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group my-1">
              <select class="form-control" name="variants-1">
                {% for v in product_variant %}
                  <option value="{{ v.product_number }}">{{ v.color }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group my-1">
              <input class="form-control" type="number" name="quantity-1" min="0" placeholder="Cantidad" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

código nuevo

```
 <div class="mb-2">
    <label class="font-weight-medium">Elige un color del producto para agregar al carrito</label>
  </div>
  {% for field in form %}

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group my-1">
      {{ field.label_tag }}
      {{ field }}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

El form que estoy usando es el siguiente.

```
class CartItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = CartProduct
    fields = ['variant', 'quantity', 'logo', 'inks', 'pantones']
    labels = {
        'variant': 'Variante',
        'quantity': ' Cantidad',
        'logo': 'Logo',
        'inks': 'Tinta',
        'pantones': 'Pantones'
    }
    widgets = {
        'variant': forms.Select(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'variant-1'
        }),
         'quantity': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'quantity-1'
        }),
        'pantones': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'pantone'
        }),
         'inks': forms.Select(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'ink'
        }),
         'logo': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control'
        }),
    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias antemano

Comment: Ya deberia de aplicar el estilo porque tienes las mismas clases de CSS. Adjunta el HTML que te genera con el nuevo formulario renderizado.

Comment: disculpa creo que me explique de manera erronea , lo que busco hacer es que el html sea el mismo ya que en el aterior hay dos campos en una misma row y ahora como los pinto se pone uno por row